# Some common and minor styling

Tags: formatting

I want do some common styling please give me most simple, neat and clear solution for following:

- How can I indicate space between paragraphs? I want distance between paragraphs be more.
- How in article class I can set main font size bigger than 12pt?
- How can I draw a very simple border in every page. (Like ms-word page borders)
- How can I insert a simple header in every page (in article class)
- How can I easily define indent size of first line of paragraph? 1st line of 1st paragraph in each section have 0 indent, how can I modify that?

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \begin{document}

  Style me!

  \end{document}
  ```

Perhaps you say that I should ask these in distinct questions, but I think the answers to all of these questions are short.

Comment: Beware of what you wish for. It may be granted unto you, thus making your work ugly.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Surly my work is going to be a little ugly! But I have to do that! :(

Comment: You're exactly right that these questions should be asked in distinct questions, no matter how simple they might be. (Voted to close)

Comment: Please ask only one question per question posts. This is an important principle on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the answer to your questions. (I really wouldn't add a frame around every page.)

```
\documentclass{article}

% Adds space between paragraphs *without* removing indentation
%     (not a good idea)
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

% Alternative which removes indentation
% \usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}

\usepackage[paperwidth=19cm,paperheight=27.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center,noinfo]{crop}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you would answer this question that so clearly breaks with our one-question-per-question rule.

Comment: @doncherry I thought "If I can answer this with about a dozen lines of code, then ... why not."

Comment: I'd argue because these simple questions, that only require a minimal amount of code, often attract the most users to tex.sx, they should still be kept separate. On top, duplicate handling gets really tricky if we answer bundled questions; and it just doesn't go along with the way of knowledge management the SE system implies. I don't mean to preach to you, I just highly value the system and rules of SE and think we should obey them more strictly than this.

Comment: @doncherry Noted; will refrain from answering (unrelated) bundled stuff.

Comment: Alright, and thanks for the constructive conversation! `:)`